# Add vertical scroll bar to panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll

I am trying to make a `Panel` scrollable, but only vertically (so `AutoScroll` won't work because the child controls go past the left edge and must).

So how is this done?

Comment: So you want to have only the vertical scroll when it's necessary? So setting the `Scrollbars` property to `Vertical` won't work?

Comment: @debracey There isn't any property called `Scrollbars` on my `Panel` and it doesn't show up in Intellisense. I have seen other people talk about it so I think it exists but I'm just doing it wrong. I get this error for this line: `panel1.Scrollbars = ScrollBars.Vertical;` -  `'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' does not contain a definition for 'Scrollbars' and no extension method 'Scrollbars' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @debracey I am using VS 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you're using winforms, default panel components does not offer you a way to disable the horizontal scrolling components. A workaround of this is to disable the auto scrolling and add a scrollbar yourself:

```
ScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
vScrollBar1.Scroll += (sender, e) => { panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value; };
panel1.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
```

Detailed discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winforms/thread/6b9c2c72-e91a-40f0-a835-c12328490c0c).

Comment: I really don't want to do this 'hack'. How can I do it manually with a `VScrollBar` component?

Comment: @Teoman that example doesn't help, I can do that with the forms designer. What is the formula for determining what the max/min values of the scroll bar should be, how do I offset controls inside the panel when the scrollbar scrolls down, etc?

Comment: All you need is to sync `VerticalScroll.Value` properties with the `Scroll` event. Updated the code. Note that to get the scroll effect, there should be some elements overflowing from the bottom edge of the panel (i.e. there should be some not-visible elements to scroll to).

Comment: @Teoman How do I get the size of the grip in the scroll bar to change as there becomes more or less things "overflowing" from the bottom? And I just tried code very similar to yours and when I scroll down, everything jerks violently all around and doesn't scroll (even though there is stuff to scroll to in that instance).

Comment: This may help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winforms/thread/6b9c2c72-e91a-40f0-a835-c12328490c0c

Comment: @Teoman when it transitions from not overflowing to overflowing the horizontal scrollbar appears for a second and disappears, but I guess I'll have to settle for that. Thanks.

Comment: When I on a control that has another control that is derived from ScrollabeControl, and I use the scrollbar, the vertical and horizontal scrollbar inside the ScrollabeControl are shown and hidden very quickly (flickering) and the contents doesn't seem to scroll as smooth as its own scrollbar. @Microsoft winforms department: How hard can it be to only have one scrollbar on control!

Comment: This does not work at all...the scrollbar scrolls with the content, so when you scroll down you can't see the top up button on the scrollbar

Answer (score 52):

Try this instead for 'only' scrolling vertical.
(auto scroll needs to be false before it will accept changes)

```
mypanel.AutoScroll = false;
mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
mypanel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
mypanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: Very good point for bringing up the fact that `AutoScroll` needs to be set to false, thankyou

Answer (score 6):

`AutoScroll` is really the solution!
You just have to set `AutoScrollMargin` to `0, 1000` or something like this, then use it to scroll down and add buttons and items there!

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, show a code example etc

Answer (score 5):

`Panel` has an `AutoScroll` property. Just set that property to `True` and the panel will automatically add a scroll bar when needed.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that `AutoScroll` is not a solution

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code that implements custom vertical scrollbar. The important detail here is to know when scrollbar is needed by calculating how much space is consumed by the controls that you add to the panel.

```
panelUserInput.SuspendLayout();
panelUserInput.Controls.Clear();
panelUserInput.AutoScroll = false;
panelUserInput.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;

// here you'd be adding controls

int x = 20, y = 20, height = 0;
for (int inx = 0; inx < numControls; inx++ )
{
    // this example uses textbox control
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    // add whatever details you need for this control
    // before adding it to the panel
    panelUserInput.Controls.Add(txt);
    height = y + txt.Height;
    y += 25;
}
if (height > panelUserInput.Height)
{
    VScrollBar bar = new VScrollBar();
    bar.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    bar.Scroll += (sender, e) => { panelUserInput.VerticalScroll.Value =  bar.Value; };
    bar.Top = 0;
    bar.Left = panelUserInput.Width - bar.Width;
    bar.Height = panelUserInput.Height;
    bar.Visible = true;
    panelUserInput.Controls.Add(bar);
}
panelUserInput.ResumeLayout();

// then update the form
this.PerformLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

3 steps:

1- just set AutoScroll property to true

2-   in    Form load()add the following:

```
   my Panel Vertical Scroll Maximum = 10000
```

3- after my Panel controls Add(item) add the following:
Invalidate();
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer by Kamgman which does work.

Let's say we were adding a label as the child control to the panel:

- First add the panel. Set `AutoScroll` to True and `AutoSize` to False.
- Add a label into the panel. Set `AutoSize` to true. You could give it a `MinimumSize` for the Width if you like so that it at least keeps its "shape" horizontally.
- Then set the `Anchor` for the label control to **Top** only. Remove the Left anchor on it. This ensures the label only scrolls vertically but not horizontally.

If you go this route you don't have to add the lines to hide the horizontal scroll bar.

It might also be better if you're using `System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources` to load it from the `.resx` file instead of the `.Designer.cs` . Because in my case whenever I make edits to this particular form I lose the changes in the `Designer.cs` file. But that will come down to how your project is set up

Answer (score -2):

Add to your panel's style code something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="Server" CssClass="myPanelCSS" style="overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden"></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: OP asked about Winforms (its in the tags) I guess that is why you got the down vote.