# Can you make a listview or similar of small functional forms or equivalent as shown in picture?

Tags: c#

I need to make a list(view?) containing individual forms, or objects that can mimic my needs (buttons, labels, images) preferably resizeable if a button is pushed so I can expand downwards and show a textbox that can contain info and/or be edited)

[image: Example]

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to create such a form as posted above?

Comment: What about adding a scrollbar to the panel? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090558/add-vertical-scroll-bar-to-panel-in-net

Comment: create a usercontrol and add instances of it to a flowlayoutpanel.

Comment: I havent really tried anything yet. Maybe i was a bit vague in my description of what i need. Think Outlook list of mail with added button (or equivalent) functionality. Of course the list needs to be dynamic, add, remove etc, and scrollable. The idea of a user Control on a flowlayoutpanel seems interesting but how do i implement scrolling?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on user Control and flowlayoutpanel. Worked a charm! Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is olved using TaW  suggestion in the comments above.
Many thanks