# Why I don't see enabled vertical scroll bar on the textbox when setting it?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars ScrollBars { get; set; }

        private int startingY = 0;
        private GroupBox lastGB = null;
        private int timerCounter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { UpdateLabelPositions(); };
            textBox1.LocationChanged += (s, e) => { UpdateLabelPositions(); };
            this.Shown += (s, e) => { UpdateLabelPositions(); };

            textBox1.Multiline = true;
            textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
        }
```

but the textBox scroll bar is grayed out disabled even if I'm adding to it many items.

I'm adding to the textBox many groupboxes but like in the screenshot they are added down inside the textbox and the textbox don't have enabled scrollbars. I tried also in the designer to set the scroll bars to BOTH but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Wait.. you're adding Controls inside TextBox? Why not a proper container like Panel?

Comment: @Martheen I changed it to panel and still it's not scrolling. and I can't find in the designer of the panel where and how to set and enable the scrollbars.  but as before with the textbox also with the panel no scrollbars.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090558/add-vertical-scroll-bar-to-panel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489273/how-do-i-disable-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated a basic *Panel* with 4 *GroupBoxes* inside and set `AutoScroll` to *true* and the vertical scroll bar displayed as expected:

[image: Panel with scroll bar]

Obviously, `AutoSize` must be set to *false*, so is it possible that you have some conflicting properties set?